# Linear algebra practice quiz question considering subsets and dimensions of the intersections of subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Bbb R^{(2,2)}$ be the vector space of real matrices with two rows and two columns.

Let us consider the subsets of $\Bbb R^{(2,2)}$:

$$V=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\b&0\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

and

$$W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&k\\h&d\end{pmatrix}:k,h,d\in\Bbb R\right\}\,.$$

Which of the following is correct?

(a) $\dim(V \cup W)=1$.

(b) $\dim(V \cap W)=0$.

(c) $V$ is not a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^{(2,2)}$.

(d) $V \subset W$.

The correct answer is (d).

I apologise first of all for not knowing how to write the problem using mathjax I tried and I couldn't do it!
I found this problem in some of my Linear Algebra practice tests that we have in our university website! I tried for some time and I couldn't figure it out how to solve this! Can you help me?

Comment: Check out this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference):)

Comment: @Noah I did but there was tooo much to memorise! My Linear Algebra exam is in 5 days and i can't afford to do that right now! Much apprechiated tho!

Comment: Do you know what (d) means?

Comment: @mrsamy What do you mean?

Comment: You said the correct answer is (d). What is your question about it?

Comment: @mrsamy I wanted to know the thought process on how you arrive at that conclusion in case i encounter a similar problem in the exam !

Comment: Well, hence my question, do you understand what "$V\subset W$" means?

Comment: @mrsamy Yes? V is included in W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Observe that $V\cup W=W$ and $V\cap W=V$. So in order to see whether (a) and (b) are true, find $\dim(V)$ and $\dim(W)$.

For (c), go over the concept of "subspaces", which tells you that $V$ *is* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{(2,2)}$.

For (d), $V\subset W$ means every matrix $A\in V$ is an element of $W$.

Comment: THanks a lot! I'll try that then